# DXA using properties in cd_client_conf.xml

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

I was wondering if it was possible to use properties in the cd_client_conf.xml? I was expecting the same behaviour as the WEB8 microservices. In those microservices configuration files you can set ${property.name} and just add VM options to fill them in.

The problem we are trying to solve is that we want as little of environment configuration as possible within our git repository and move it to machines themselves. We are using spring profiles set within the tomcats to specify which profile is active. Now we want to do something similar for the configuration files within /classes.

Kr,

Thomas

Comment: Which CIL version are you using ? This support was not there in 8.2 and added in later releases.

Comment: DXA 1.5 uses CIL 8.2

Comment: So we have to keep different cd_client_conf.xml files for each environment as long as we keep using DXA 1.5?

Comment: You can probably combine DXA 1.5 with a newer CIL version, but this has not been tested. Indeed, it's recommended to use a newer DXA version.

Answer (score 1):

From CIL's perspective, as mentioned by Rick in comments, since DXA 1.5 uses 8.2 CIL, property placeholder for client configuration `(cd_client_conf.xml)`is not implemented. So, upgrade to newer version of DXA (which has newer CIL) is suggested approach where this feature is available.

Comment: Which CIL version has the feature? CIL 8.3? Both Java and .NET?

Comment: In CIL Java 8.3 (which uses cd_client_conf.xml) this feature was introduced. Not implemented in .Net.

Comment: OK, that means you will have to use DXA  Java 1.6 or higher to benefit from this feature.